# Program freezes after clicking button?

Tags: c#

When I click a button, the program freezes.
I am trying to reach file.bat in h folder of the root directory.
this is my code for click event:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            string pathName = textBox.Text;
            pathName = Path.GetFileName(pathName);

            string dir = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
            string dirEnd = dir + "\\h\\";

            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + dirEnd + "file.bat" + "\"";
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();

            MessageBox.Show("Program has been started!");

        }
```

If I remove `proc.WaitForExit();` nothing will happen but the program wont freeze. 
But if I remove `proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` the CMD will start but the argument wont be passed to it.

Comment: your path to the file is \\h\file.bat\.    if its the h drive then the path should be h:\file.bat

Comment: When you run debug where does it throw a error? You have double brackets at the top of the method does look right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Process.WaitForExit();
```

From the docs:

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.

This means that the `Process.WaitForExit();` method blocks until the process finishes. If the process runs for a long time your application will just wait, it's not actually frozen, it's just doing what it's told.

If you don't actually want to wait for it to finish and show your message instead just remove the statement like this:

```
proc.Start();
MessageBox.Show("Program has been started!");
```

### Edit

There's something wrong with your argument. While debuging, remove `proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` and `proc.WaitForExit();` so you can see what happens.

Build your argument string in a seperate variable and inspect it to make sure it's correct.

If you want to run a command with `cmd.exe`, you need to pass the `/C` argument. For example: `cmd.exe ping` won't work, you must use `cmd.exe /C ping`. In your case the argument should probably be something like: `/C path/to/file.bat`.

Comment: The argument is still not passed to CMD.

Comment: If you want to run a command with `cmd.exe`, you need to pass the `/C` argument. For example: `cmd.exe ping` won't work, you must use `cmd.exe /C ping`. In your case the argument should probably be something like: `/C path/to/file.bat`

Answer (score 2):

This line will make your program hang:

`proc.WaitForExit();`

You will never get to the messagebox showing because the application is waiting for your process to exit. Just remove proc.WaitForExit() and your message will show while the process is still running in the background. However, if you do this you have to make sure everything is handled properly (i.e. process dies when your application closes)

Comment: If I remove proc.WaitForExit(); nothing will happen but the program wont freeze. but if I delete proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; the cmd will start but the argument wont be passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx), `WaitForExit` waits for the associated process to exit, and *blocks the current thread of execution* until the time has elapsed or the process has exited.  'The current thread' being the thread that you launched it from; in this case, your main program, causing your hang.